# tqdm keeps printing progress bar in the same line

Tags: python, pytorch, tqdm

i am trying to train a network, but the progress bar for "tqdm" is not working properly, it keeps printing a new bar one after the other in the same line, i don't know why this is happening, but to my understanding i should i just call tqdm in the for-loop initialization and that's it, also it seems like the estimated time on the progress bar might be off, could this also have to do with how the model is implemented, when i run the code it doesn't allocate the entire VRAM of the GPU.
my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from tqdm import tqdm


def loss_fn(outputs, targets):
    return nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()(outputs, targets.view(-1, 1))


def train_fn(data_loader, model, optimizer, device, scheduler):
    model.train()

    for bi, d in tqdm(enumerate(data_loader), total=len(data_loader) , leave = False):
        ids = d["ids"]
        token_type_ids = d["token_type_ids"]
        mask = d["mask"]
        targets = d["targets"]

        ids = ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
        token_type_ids = token_type_ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
        mask = mask.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
        targets = targets.to(device, dtype=torch.float)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(ids=ids, mask=mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids)

        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()


def eval_fn(data_loader, model, device):
    model.eval()
    fin_targets = []
    fin_outputs = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for bi, d in tqdm(enumerate(data_loader), total=len(data_loader)):
            ids = d["ids"]
            token_type_ids = d["token_type_ids"]
            mask = d["mask"]
            targets = d["targets"]

            ids = ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
            token_type_ids = token_type_ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
            mask = mask.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
            targets = targets.to(device, dtype=torch.float)

            outputs = model(ids=ids, mask=mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids)
            fin_targets.extend(targets.cpu().detach().numpy().tolist())
            fin_outputs.extend(torch.sigmoid(outputs).cpu().detach().numpy().tolist())
    return fin_outputs, fin_targets
```

the output:
[image]

Comment: What happens when you use this: `enumerate(tqdm(data_loader))` instead?

Comment: same thing, i tried running the same code in pycharm, and it seems to run fine, i don't know what's wrong with my shell.

Comment: Maybe `from tqdm.auto import tqdm` will help you